# server-side api vs client-side api

Tags: 2010

We are planning to develop a ticketing and file/document delivery system.

We will be using sharepoint at the background, and will develop our custom interface.

In terms of the articles and discussions, the performance of server and client side apis is better than web services(obviously). so web service option dropped from our list.

Apparently, Server-side api is more comprehensive than client-side api, but what are the things that cannot be done in client-side api, but can be done in server-side api? is there any comparison of these two?

In [one of the articles I have read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313619.aspx), it says that

> Any application that uses these APIs must be physically deployed on the server.
>
> For example, the server-side object model provides the most extensive set of options for developing customizations, but it can only be used on computers that are running a version of SharePoint 2010

If I use server-side dlls on my custom project, will the application server require Sharepoint to be installed?

Comment: Just to add a comment here. I think the COM is great for smaller tasks like data aggregation, but anything serious I would consider writing a custom WCF service that could allow you to wrap the server-side api and gain access to parts of the object model that the COM does not have like versioning.

Comment: I'm curious why web services were dropped immediately. Can you explain why you think it would be slow? Also when @RobertKaucher said COM I thought [Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) instead of **Client Object Model**.

Comment: so you mean that, I should write wrapper service and host it in Sharepoint server. Then consume it on the application which I am going to write? Would that have performance issues though?

Comment: @KitMenke it was stated in an MSDN article, that is why it dropped. I would be grateful if there is a comparison in terms of performance though.

Comment: I assume the context of this forum gives COM the meaning of Client Object Model unless the context would be switched based on the content of the post, but point taken. I'm also curious as to why web services were dropped as an option, especially since the client object model uses the same web services that are considered slow by the questioner.

Comment: this is from msdn article; "The Web services provide a fuller range of capabilities than the managed client object model, but they do not provide the same performance and design advantages, such as batching and exception handling. When you develop client-side applications, you should use the managed client object model whenever possible."

Comment: any comment on this guys?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the server side API from Microsoft.SharePoint.dll (so called server side object model) ONLY LOCALLY on the SharePoint frontend webserver machine. It's by design.